# Disabling input type="image" as button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image as a button..I want to disable the image onclick...How can I do that?

```
<input type="image" src="someimage.png" height="20px" width="20px"  name="button" />
```

Comment: disable the image or the input? were do you click?

Comment: The image is acting as a button..So disabling the image would eventually disable the input./button

Comment: if you're just removing the clickable functionality, why are you using `input` at all?

Answer (score 5):

html(add id):

```
<input id="btn" type="image" src="someimage.png" height="20px" width="20px"  name="button" />
```

js:

```
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function(){
  this.disabled = true
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Dtgb4/

Or you can just add attribute **onclick="this.disabled = true"**

update for comment:

You can use CSS rule `:disabled` for styling disabled buttons

http://jsfiddle.net/Dtgb4/1/

P.S. pseudo-class :disabled only for modern browsers(not for IE8-).

Comment: I mean I want the image to be looked as if it is disabled.... If I dont give an image and simply give the input type = "button"..then on disabling the button it will actually look disabled..I want that...

Comment: Add a css rule which will fade out the button/image a bit when disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a specific reason to use the input type, you shouldn't be using it for image.

```
<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
```

use the image type, and no onclick handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<button height="20px" width="20px"  name="button"><img src="someimage.png"/></button>
```

and now you can disable button as normal as everything